# In R, create/fill a column of a data frame based on an approximate numerical match to values in a second data frame

Tags: r, matching

I have two data frames. The first data frame contains a list of drugs with the time I saw them in the experiment. The second data frame contains a list of the standards I ran with my experiment - so it's another list of drugs with the expected time to see them.

What I am trying to do is get the name of the right standard to be assigned to the right drug in the first data frame.

For example, drug A was seen at 5.5 minutes. Drug A's standard is seen at 5.7 minutes.

Drug B was observed at 6 minutes. It uses the same standard as Drug A, at 5.7 minutes.

Drug C was observed at 6.5 minutes. It uses a standard which is seen at 7 minutes.

Example of original data frames:

```
DF1:
Drug   Time
 A     5.5
 B     6.0
 C     6.5

DF2:
Standard   Time
 S1        5.7
 S2        7
```

The key is I want R to look for the standard with the *closest* time (in either the positive or negative direction) to one of the standards in DF2 and then assign the name of that standard (S1, S2) to DF1.

Example of final data frame:

```
Drug   Time   Standard
 A      5.5     S1
 B      6.0     S1
 C      6.5     S2
```

I know how I could get perfectly matched values to be assigned - but I'm unsure how to make R do the searching for the closest value in DF2 to the time value for each row in DF1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lapply and rbind, a not so clean approach. I am sure we will see some dplyr magic :)

```
DF1 = read.table(text="Drug   Time
A     5.5
B     6.0
C     6.5",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


DF2 = read.table(text="Standard   Time
S1        5.7
S2        7",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

For each  "Time" observation we find the minimum absolute "Standard" observation and create data frame containing the (time,standard) set.

In the end,we combine all data frame sets through rbind.

`DF2$Standard[which.min(abs(DF2$Time - x) )]` this finds the "Standard" with the above condition

```
DF3 = do.call(rbind,lapply(DF1$Time,function(x) {
      data.frame(Time=x,Standard=DF2$Standard[which.min(abs(DF2$Time - x) )],stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      }))

final_DF = merge(DF1,DF3,by="Time")[,union(names(DF1), names(DF3))
final_DF
#  Drug Time Standard
#1    A  5.5       S1
#2    B  6.0       S1
#3    C  6.5       S2
```

Comment: ask and ye shall receive: `DF1 %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(diff = DF2$Standard[which.min(abs(Time-DF2$Time))])`